# Zend Gdata Calendar: setQuery with exact phrase match?

Tags: php, zend-framework, google-calendar-api, google-data-api, zend-gdata

I am having trouble using `Zend_Gdata_Calendar` to return a subset of Google Calendar events with an exact phrase match.

The [reference guide for `Zend_Gdata_Books`](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.11/en/zend.gdata.books.html), in the `setQuery()` section, suggests this should be possible with Zend:

> Note that any spaces, quotes or other punctuation in the parameter value must be URL-escaped (Use a plus (+) for a space). To search for an exact phrase, enclose the phrase in quotation marks. For example, to search for books matching the phrase "spy plane", set the `q` parameter to `%22spy+plane%22`.

As far as I can tell, `Zend_Gdata_Books` and `Zend_Gdata_Calendar` extend the same `setQuery()` function, so I figure they're equivalent on the Zend end of things.

As for Google, the [Calendar query parameters reference](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v2/reference#Parameters) says the Calendar API supports the standard Data API query parameters, which in turn says the full-text query string `q` supports case-insensitive exact phrase searching, just as `Zend_Gdata_Books` indicates.

I've tried it all these ways:

```
$gCal = new Zend_Gdata_Calendar();
$query = $gCal->newEventQuery();

$query->setQuery("%22event+text%22"); //no results
$query->setQuery("%22event%20text%22"); //no results
$query->setQuery("\"event text\""); //too many results
$query->setQuery('"event text"'); //too many results
$query->setQuery("event text"); //too many results
```

I realize the first two didn't work because the string is getting doubly URL-encoded. In the latter cases, I am getting the event I want, but also events including "event" or "text" that I don't want.

Could it be that Google has implemented the full-text query differently for the Calendar API? What kind of dumb things might I be doing on my end to break it?

Answer (score 0):

it looks like you want try it with `$query->setQuery('"event text"');` 
which yields the query string of `Query string(19) "?q=%22event+text%22"`
where `$query->setQuery("event text");`
yields the query string of `Query string(13) "?q=event+text"`

I used :

```
$gCal = new Zend_Gdata_Calendar();
        $query = $gCal->newEventQuery();
        $query->setQuery("event text");
        Zend_Debug::dump($query->getQueryString(), 'Query');
```

To test.

Comment: Thank you very much - I hadn't realized I could check the query string (I am new to Zend). It looks like `'"event text"'` and `"/"event text/""` are both generating the query string I want, but in both cases I'm still receiving too many events (events including `event` or `text` by themselves) -- almost as though Google is discarding the quote marks before searching.